# Proving a function is in big theta using limit method

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, proof

Hi I am faced with a problem of proving that a function is an element of big theta. The question reads as follows: is 4n^3+23n^2+1 (is an element of) Theta(n^3), and prove your answer. My answer  is as follows:
[image: ans]
Basically I am proving it is in both  in big oh and big omega and if so it is in big theta. Is this correct? Also, what is the best way of proving that a given function is in big theta using limits?

Comment: Be aware that the second limit is `1/4`, not infinity. In fact, it is the reciprocal of the first limit (which is `4` as you put it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show that `f(n) = 4n^3 + 23n^2 - 1` belongs in `Theta(n^3)`, you have to bound it between `k1.n^3` and `k2.n^3`for some positive constants `k1` and `k2` when `n` is sufficiently large (meaning, `n >= n0` for some constant `n0`)

Let's see this without and with limits.

**Without limits**

Given that

```
1 < 23n^2
```

for all `n >= 1`, we get

```
0 < 23n^2 - 1
```

and therefore

```
4n^3 = 4n^3 + 0
     < 4n^3 + 23n^2 - 1
```

Hence, you can take `k1 = 4`.

Now for the upper bound.

```
4n^3 + 23n^2 - 1 < 4n^3 + 23n^2
                 < 23n^3 + 23n^2
                 <= 23n^3 + 23n^3
                 = 46n^3
```

and you can take `k2 = 46` and `n0 = 1`.

---

**With limits**

```
lim f(n)/n^3 = lim 4 + 23/n - 1/n^3 = 4
```

Therefore, given `epsilon > 0` there exists `n0` such that

```
| f(n)/n^3 - 4 | < epsilon
```

for `n >= n0`. Take `epsilon = 1`. We get

```
-1 < f(n)/n^3 - 4 < 1
```

or

```
3 < f(n)/n^3 < 5
```

or

```
3n^3 < f(n) < 5n^3
```

and you can take `k1=3`, `k2=5` and the value of `n0` that exists for `epsilon = 1`.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped, although what is your final conclusion

Comment: The final conclusion is that the function is actually BigTheta(n^3). Let me know if you need further clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

In the computation of Big-Omega you need to find the limit of your function divided by n<sup>3</sup> (that's the opposite of what you did). Since it equals to 4 (which is obviously less than infinity), your function belongs to Omega(n<sup>3</sup>).

Comment: if I divide by n^3, won't it be proving its in big Oh and not Omega?

Comment: For big-O you actually need a limit around a real number rather than infinity. Anyway, big-O is usually proved differently: there is n0 so that for each n>n0: 4n^3+23n^2-1 < 4n^3+23n^3 = 27n^3 = O(n^3)